# Не импортируется библиотека android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

Я пытаюсь создать календарь по туториалу- https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview.
Проблема в том, что Андроид Студио не может найти эти библиотеки:

```
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import com.calendar.MainActivity;
import com.calendar.R;
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

2 Gradle файл:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
```

Также, я пробовала вместо первой строчки

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

вот это

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Попробуйте `import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat` вместо `import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Новый подход — использование [`androidx`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) библиотек. Использовать support-v4, support-v7 и прочее уже не нужно. Вот здесь [таблица](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) соответствия классов.

В вашем случае для ContextCompat нужно использовать следующий импорт:

```kotlin
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
```

Этот класс находится в библиотеке `androidx.core:core`, которая у вас уже есть в проекте, так как у вас подключена `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`.

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает

Comment: Если все ок, то отметьте данный ответ как правильный, нажав на зеленую галочку слева.

Comment: Я пыталась, но у меня мало опыта. мой голос не засчитывается.